# Loading extension GLX : screen freezes

Tags: xorg, desktop, ubuntu-12.10

I installed Ubuntu Server edition 12.10 on a server (with 16 GB RAM and 500GB hard disk).
The installation was successful, after which I tried installing GUI using the below command
**`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`**  Now, the problem is I'm not able to start GUI from the terminal once I login. When I do startx, screen freezes and nothing works.
In the terminal, it displays loading extension GLX and stops.
I did **`grep EE /var/log/Xorg.0.log`**  which displayed the following lines.
**`[  247.145] (EE) open /dev/dri/card): No such file or directory`**
Why does this error occur. How can I solve this.

Comment: question answered here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/265761/loading-extension-glx-screen-freezes